# what does 'this' mean in this backbone statement?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript “this” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

I am now learning backbone by checking the codes of the todos app as an example. I am very confused with the codes `this.model.bind('change', this.render);` what does the two this mean in this statement? somebody give me an explanation?

Comment: Consider [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: How much Javascript do you know? Do you understand what `this` means in general?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that code is inside `initialize` function of your view components, so `this` is the view itself.